# Менять класс у элементов по клику

Tags: javascript, css

Ни получается выполнить следующее:
при нажатии на бургер `<div class="bar"></div>`

1. для body присваивался класс `pushy-active` (для затемнения заднего фона)
2. чтобы к контейнеру с `class="menu-collapsed"`  добавлялся класс `menu-expanded` (на данный момент только это нормально выполняется)
3. Чтобы всё это (в пункте 1 и 2) убиралось по клику ТУДА СЮДА и бургеру

Помогите пожалуйста составить javascript правильно

```js
$(".menu-collapsed").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("menu-expanded");
});
$("body").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("pushy-active");
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand);
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: #242729;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.b-a, .bar, .bar:before, .bar:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #2b7087;
}

.menu-collapsed {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-collapsed ul {
  transition: all 0s;
  position: fixed;
  left: -9000px;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 212px;
  top: 24px;
}
.bar:before {
  top: -8px;
}
.bar:after {
  top: 8px;
}

.b-a-expanded, .menu-expanded .bar:before, .menu-expanded .bar:after {
  transition: all .25s;
  top: -0px;
}

.pushy-active {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 19;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: fade 500ms;
  -moz-animation: fade 500ms;
  -o-animation: fade 500ms;
  animation: fade 500ms;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 19;
  -webkit-animation: fade 500ms;
  -moz-animation: fade 500ms;
  -o-animation: fade 500ms;
  animation: fade 500ms;
}

.puleft {
  transform: translate3d(-300px, 0, 0);
}

.menu-expanded {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.menu-expanded ul {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu-expanded a {
  transition: all .15s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  display: block;
}
.menu-expanded a:hover {
  color: #1d1d1d;
}
.menu-expanded .bar {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.menu-expanded .bar:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-expanded .bar:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

p {
  line-height: 160%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="menu-collapsed">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Туда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Сюда</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class=" ">
        <br>
        <p>Много текста</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Код вообще не связан с описанным желаемым поведением о_О Где обработчик клика по "бугеру"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.bar').on('click', function(){
  $('body').toggleClass('pushy-active');
  $('.menu-collapsed').toggleClass('menu-expanded');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand);
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: #242729;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.b-a, .bar, .bar:before, .bar:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #2b7087;
}

.menu-collapsed {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-collapsed ul {
  transition: all 0s;
  position: fixed;
  left: -9000px;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 212px;
  top: 24px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.bar:before {
  top: -8px;
}
.bar:after {
  top: 8px;
}

.b-a-expanded, .menu-expanded .bar:before, .menu-expanded .bar:after {
  transition: all .25s;
  top: -0px;
}

.pushy-active {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 19;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: fade 500ms;
  -moz-animation: fade 500ms;
  -o-animation: fade 500ms;
  animation: fade 500ms;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 19;
  -webkit-animation: fade 500ms;
  -moz-animation: fade 500ms;
  -o-animation: fade 500ms;
  animation: fade 500ms;
}

.puleft {
  transform: translate3d(-300px, 0, 0);
}

.menu-expanded {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.menu-expanded ul {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu-expanded a {
  transition: all .15s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  display: block;
}
.menu-expanded a:hover {
  color: #1d1d1d;
}
.menu-expanded .bar {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.menu-expanded .bar:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-expanded .bar:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

p {
  line-height: 160%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="menu-collapsed">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Туда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Сюда</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class=" ">
        <br>
        <p>Много текста</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

А вообще я бы советовал обернуть "кнопку бургера" в блок и по нему обрабатывать клик, ибо `target` применяется к трём палкам `.bar`.. Сложно объяснил.

Comment: по второму клику по бургеру не возвращает исходное значения

Comment: @Алекс31, исправил. Переделайте "кнопку бургера", посмотрите через инспектор область его `target`.. Если сказать простым языком, то кнопка работать нормально, при условие, что курсор находится точно в центре кнопки.